# Invoke Rest API from an Azure Runbook ( Powershell) to scale up and Down an Azure Synapse Database

Tags: powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook, azure-autoscaling-block

I've created an Azure Powershell Runbook to scale UP or Down a Datawarehouse dedicated SQL Pool using the Invoke-RestMethod but is failing with the following error:

```
At line:31 char:11 + $Body = @ + ~ Unrecognized token in source text. At line:36 char:6 + "name" = "DW500c" + ~~~~~~ The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept assignments, such as a variable or a property.
```

Here is the code being used

```
$Url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/$sqlServerName/databases/$SynapseSqlPoolName?api-version=2020-08-01-preview HTTP/1.1 Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    $Body = @ 
        {
            location: "West Europe",
            "sku":
            {
                "name" = "DW500c"
            }
        }       

    Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $url -Body $body -UseBasicParsing
```

I've tried to change the "=" with ":" but it gives the same error

I've tried with the solution below provided by Mathias but I'm getting a new error

```
$Body = @{
        location = "West Europe"
        sku = @{
            name = "DW500c"
        }
    }
```

Error:

The remote server returned an error ( 400) Bad Request

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"code":"MissingApiVersionParameter","message":"The api-version query parameter (?api-version=) is required for all requests."}} At line:38 char:3 + Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $url -Body $body -UseBasi ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Latest code but getting "The specified content type is invalid"

```
$Url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/$sqlServerName/databases/$SynapseSqlPoolName?api-version=2020-08-01-preview" 
    $ContentType = "HTTP/1.1 Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    $Body = @{
        location = "West Europe"
        sku = @{
            name = "DW500c"
        }
    }       

    Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $url -ContentType $ContentType -Body $body -UseBasicParsing
```

The problem with the Content Type has been fixed but I'm still getting the api version error . Below is the full code

```
Param
(
    # This is the Resource group where Azure Synapse Analytics SQL Pool is located   
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]  
    [String] $resourceGroupName
    ,
    # This is the name of the Azure SQL Server hosting the Azure Synapse Analytics SQL Pool
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]  
    [String] $sqlServerName
    ,
    # This is the name of the Azure Synapse Analytics SQL Pool
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]  
    [String] $SynapseSqlPoolName
    ,
    # This is the name of the Azure Synapse Analytics SQL Pool
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]  
    [String] $SubscriptionId
    ,
    # This is the name of the Azure Synapse Analytics SQL Pool
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]  
    [String] $Sku
)

    $ConnectionName = 'AzureRunAsConnection'
    $ServicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $ConnectionName

    'Log in to Azure...'
    $null = Connect-AzAccount `
    -ServicePrincipal `
    -TenantId $ServicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
    -ApplicationId $ServicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
    -CertificateThumbprint $ServicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 

    $Url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/$sqlServerName/databases/$SynapseSqlPoolName?api-version=2020-08-01-preview" 
    $ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    $Body = @{
        location = "West Europe"
        sku = @{
            name = $Sku
        }
    }       

    Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $url -ContentType $ContentType -Body $body -UseBasicParsing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mathias R. Jessen for his guidance, thanks to the 100 websites I've reviewed and to the 100 tests or more performed today , I finally found the way to make it work. We need to keep in mind that there is a different URL for a normal Azure database VS a Synapse database ( mine is synapse DB).

There are a couple of more tweaks that can be done to the code like , getting the subscriptionId and apiversion automatically instead of hardcoding it and also using some try , catch and IF condition to do the scale the Synapse DB when is not Paused but the code below accomplish what needs to done to scaleup and down a Snapse DB using a Powershell Runbook in Azure ( calling an API)

```
Param
(
    # This is the Resource group where Azure Synapse Analytics SQL Pool is located   
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]  
    [String] $resourceGroupName
    ,
    # This is the name of the Azure SQL Server hosting the Azure Synapse Analytics SQL Pool
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]  
    [String] $sqlServerName
    ,
    # This is the name of the Azure Synapse Analytics SQL Pool
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]  
    [String] $SynapseSqlPoolName
    ,
    # This is the name of the Azure Synapse Analytics SQL Pool
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]  
    [String] $Sku
    ,
    # This is the name of the Azure Synapse Analytics SQL Pool
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]  
    [String] $SubscriptionId
)

    $ConnectionName = 'AzureRunAsConnection'
    $ServicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $ConnectionName

    'Log in to Azure...'
    $null = Connect-AzAccount `
    -ServicePrincipal `
    -TenantId $ServicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
    -ApplicationId $ServicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
    -CertificateThumbprint $ServicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint

    $azContext = Get-AzContext
    $azProfile = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile
    $profileClient = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient -ArgumentList ($azProfile)
    $token = $profileClient.AcquireAccessToken($azContext.Subscription.TenantId)

    
    $authHeader = @{
        'Content-Type'='application/json'
        'Authorization'='Bearer '+$token.AccessToken
        }   


    $apiversion = "2021-06-01"
    $Url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/$sqlServerName/sqlPools/$SynapseSqlPoolName"+"?api-version=$apiversion" 
    $ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    $Body = @{
        location = "westeurope"
        sku = @{
            name = $Sku
        }
    }   

    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method PUT -Headers $authHeader -Body ($body|ConvertTo-Json) ## -UseBasicParsing
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried to change the "=" with ":" but it gives the same error

That'd be the correct course of action, but make sure you use a hashtable literal (`@{ ... }`) for the inner `sku` object too:

```
$Body = @{
    location = "West Europe"
    sku = @{
        name = "DW500c"
    }
}
```

---

It appears that the string value you assign to `$Url` contains a little more than just the URL - remove the trailing HTTP header garbage from the URL, and then pass the Content-Type header value to the `-ContentType` parameter of `Invoke-RestMethod`:

```
$Url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/$sqlServerName/databases/$SynapseSqlPoolName?api-version=2020-08-01-preview" 
$ContentType = 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'

# ...

Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $url -ContentType $ContentType -Body $body -UseBasicParsing
```

Comment: I got another error after doing the suggested update , I've edited my question and added there

Comment: @JoshSama It's probably because of the trailing request header values in `$Url`. Should be `$Url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/$sqlServerName/databases/$SynapseSqlPoolName?api-version=2020-08-01-preview"`. If you want to pass an explicit `Content-Type` header, use `Invoke-RestMethod`'s `-ContentType` parameter

Comment: I've tried that but I see now, "The specified content type is invalid.. I've updated my question

Comment: Should I remove the rest and just leave "application/json"

Comment: @JoshSama That's because `"HTTP/1.1 Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8"` is not a valid MIME type, you want `-ContentType 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'`.

Comment: @JoshSama It almost looks like you copy-pasted this data from the first three lines of a raw HTTP request. You might want to [read up on what the individual components of an HTTP message header mean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages) :)

Comment: @JoshSama `;charset=UTF-8` is a valid (and meaningful) part of the content type descriptor, but the stuff leading up to `application/json` is not part of it.

Comment: let me read the URL you just provided, I've added the full code to the question and the issue with the content type seems to be fixed but is going back to the API Version error :/